# Is it possible to execute stored procedure through a Linked server

Tags: sql-server-2005, oracle10g

Is it posible to execute Oracle 10g stored procedure on a sql 2005 Linked Server.

Comment: **Yes**. Check this link out. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlsmoanddmo/thread/12e9c126-496b-49ad-9bf7-4320f7d09af8